# Bitwise negation of XMM register

Tags: assembly, x86, bit-manipulation, sse, bitwise-not

How to get bitwise negation of values in XMM register? As far as I know there is no such instruction. The only instruction with negation is `pandn`, but to use it to simply negate values in one XMM register, I would have to have another XMM register padded filled with `1`.

Is there another way to negate bits in XMM register? Or is there a clever way to fill XMM register with `1` without accessing memory?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To load a register with all 1s, use

```
pcmpeqd xmm0, xmm0
```

After that you can simply subtract `xmmX` from `xmm0` to get `~xmmX`, or use `pandn`

You can also load other constants to xmm registers easily

```
pcmpeqd xmm0, xmm0
psrld   xmm0, 30   ; 3 (32-bit)

pcmpeqd xmm0, xmm0 ; -1

pcmpeqw xmm0, xmm0 ; 1.5f
pslld   xmm0, 24
psrld   xmm0, 2

pcmpeqw xmm0, xmm0 ; -2.0f
pslld   xmm0, 30
```

Read Agner Fog's optimization guide, [13.4 Generating constants - Making constants for integer vectors in XMM registers](http://www.agner.org/optimize/optimizing_assembly.pdf)

Comment: ...or `pxor` with the all-ones register.

Comment: `psubd` and `pandn` have zero advantage over `pxor`.  Worse throughput for `psubd`, and neither are commutative.

Comment: [Constant floats with SIMD](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6565556/995714), [What are the best instruction sequences to generate vector constants on the fly?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35085059/995714)

Answer (score 5):

**Use `pxor` with an all-ones register.**

`pandn` is also usable, but has zero advantages.  There are no cases where `pandn` with an all-ones constant lets you do anything you couldn't have done with `pxor`.

`psubd` is also usable (2's complement identity), but is even worse than `pandn` because it has lower throughput on some CPUs (fewer execution ports).

---

```
pcmpedq  xmm1, xmm1      ; create the all-ones.  No false dependency.

pxor     xmm0, xmm1      ; flip all the bits in XMM0. Doesn't destroy XMM1
;pandn    xmm0, xmm1      ; equivalent but no advantage.  (~xmm0) & xmm1
```

PXOR is nice because it's commutative.  With AVX, you can load-and-NOT with one micro-fused uop:

```
vpxor    xmm0, xmm1, [rdi]
```

You can't do that with VPANDN, because the operand that can be memory or register is the not-inverted operand.  (Without AVX, though, just `movdqa` or `dqu` load and then `pxor` the load result.  A reg-copy and a micro-fused load+pxor is 3 total unfused-domain uops vs. 2)

---

Or without AVX, if you want to destroy the all-ones constant instead of the data you're inverting, `pxor` wins again:

```
movdqa  xmm2, xmm1      ; copy the all-ones constant.  Off the critical path for latency
pxor    xmm2, xmm0
```

you can take a `movdqa` off the critical path vs. `movdqa xmm2, xmm0` / `pandn xmm2,xmm1`.  (Only IvyBridge+ and Bulldozer-family/Ryzen have zero-latency `movdqa` for vector regs.)  Or if you were rematerializing the all-ones every time with `pcmpeqd` in the target register (maybe because of register pressure or because you're not doing it in a loop), that would be another case where you want `pxor` instead of `pandn`.

---

Generating an all-ones constant with `pcmpeqb/w/d` is special-cased to not have a false dependency on the old value (except on Silvermont where it does), but does still need an execution unit (unlike xor-zeroing on Sandybridge-family).  Still, it's cheap, and it's what compilers use for `_mm_set1_epi32(-1)`.

Re-creating the constant every time you need it instead of copying from another register is *slightly* worse on IvyBridge and later, and on Bulldozer-family and Ryzen.  `mov`-elimination for XMM copies avoids occupying a vector execution unit / port, in case vector-ALU execution ports were your bottleneck.

But it's slightly better on Intel P6-family (Core2/Nehalem): register-read stalls can be a problem when reading too many "cold" registers in an issue group.  (See Agner Fog's microarch pdf https://agner.org/optimize/).  P6-family is obsolete but still in use in some old machines.  You might want to tune for it in the non-AVX version of your code if you have an AVX version which runs on CPUs with AVX.  (But Haswell/Skylake "pentium" / "celeron" are still a thing, and they don't have AVX, so no-AVX doesn't mean old CPU.)

Comment: See also [Is NOT missing from SSE, AVX?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42616203) for intrinsics, and AVX-512F `vpernlogd` which gets the job done with no vector constant.