# Bitwise NOT/complement in AVX2

Tags: c++, bit-manipulation, vectorization, x86-64, avx2

It seems there is no intrinsic for bitwise NOT/complement in AVX2. Did I miss it, or are we supposed to do something like `_mm256_xor_si256(a, _mm256_set1_epi64x(-1LL))` ? If the latter, is it optimal? Is there no vector NOT instruction in assembly either?

Comment: What is C++ about this?

Comment: you mean bitwise not? because logical not is achieved by cmp instructions

Comment: @LưuVĩnhPhúc, I've changed the wording to "bitwise", if it's more clear. Though Intel's manual refers to this group of intrinsics as "logical": https://software.intel.com/sites/landingpage/IntrinsicsGuide/#expand=5212,1794,594,533,533,3146,5223,5218,5213,5226,5224,4642,3170,3170,3170,2670,4708,5068,5661,740,740,5459,5495,568,594,3889,390,3567,3576,3923,5553,2381,4929,201,406,694,4602,5003,5098,555,5089,4648,4642,5105,4893,555,5159,5340,5340,5340,307,1481,3625,415,1481,5720&techs=AVX,AVX2,FMA,Other&cats=Logical

Comment: @Yunnosch, the question is about C/C++ intrinsics.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, the only SIMD bitwise NOT is PXOR/XORPS with all-ones, in MMX, SSE*, and AVX1/2.

AVX512F can avoid the need for a separate vector constant using [`vpternlogd same,same,same`](https://hjlebbink.github.io/x86doc/html/VPTERNLOGD_VPTERNLOGQ.html), with the immediate `0x55`.  (See my answer on the duplicate for more details about it vs. `vpxord`: [Is NOT missing from SSE, AVX?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42613821/is-not-missing-from-sse-avx/46273536#46273536))

---

Ideally you can arrange your algorithm to avoid actually needing to NOT something.  For example, using `PANDN` instead of `PAND`.  Or invert later as part of something else.  But if you do end up needing to invert, that's how.

The all-ones constant can be generated with `vpcmpeqd same,same,same`.  With intrinsics, let the compiler do this for you by writing `_mm256_set1_epi32(-1)`.  (Element size is obviously irrelevant for `set1(-1)`, use whatever makes semantic sense for your algorithm.)

Comment: Yes, I end up with a need for `NOT` because there is no symmetric intrinsic for `_mm256_cmpgt_epi64()`, and then I need to `OR` the result, so no way for `AND_NOT`

Comment: @SergeRogatch: Sometimes you can rearrange things to negate an input before a compare, but yeah you can't just reverse the operands if the `==` case is special.

Comment: Posted an more about AVX512F `vpternlogd` on the duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42613821/is-not-missing-from-sse-avx/46273536#46273536.  I'd delete this but I can't because it's the accepted answer.